# What apache module could be causing this?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a legacy application running with the following link: http://10.0.0.133/?_tag=../../user

After installing this on a new server it fails with 403 Forbidden error.

I think the server is thinking it's a Directory Traversal Attack. What module could be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: What does Apache say in it's error_log? Also, do you now have everything in a vhost, so that ../../user is not in the scope of the vhost anymore?

Comment: I am getting the error_log. I don't actually have access to the server so it's kind of hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_security can cause this. Also, you may not have `DirectoryIndex` configured properly or do not grant the appropriate permissions in the containing `<Directory></Directory>` block.

Comment: I've resolved the issue by adding a whitelist mod_sec rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass `_tag` parameter with value `../../user`, replace / with %2F. Without URL encoding, apache tries to give you content of %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/?_tag=../../user directory, which does not exist.